# change 3 navigation bar background with different image

Tags: ipad, uinavigationcontroller, background, uitabbarcontroller

i have 3 navigation controller and i want to change each background using different image. I was implement a category that extends UINavigationBar like this :

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"];
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];}
```

@end

but it make every navigation bar have a same background image. And then i try to implement code like this :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
UIImageView *backGroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar insertSubview:backGroundView atIndex:0];
[backGroundView release];
```

}

in every controller but each background just show the tintColor, not the image...what should I do???

and how if i want to do that too in tabbarController??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On each of your views, implement the following in your `viewWillAppear:` method

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
...

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
     self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageBgHere"].CGImage;
}
```

Cheers,
Rog

Comment: No worries in which view are you using this code? Can you post your interface & implementation files?

Comment: sorry Rog, it change in my 1st controller. the 1st controller is inherit from UITableViewController, but in the 2nd controller (inherit from UIViewController), it's not change.